# Cannot build an Android APK with gradle 5.5.1 on Ubuntu 16 32-bit

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I used to build APK on Ubuntu 16.04 server through `gradle-2.14.1` and `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2` without a problem. Everything worked like a charm.

I needed to upgrade a build server so I've installed the newest `gradle-5.5.1` and `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2`. Now I'm not able to compile even an empty project generated in Android Studio 3.4 on Windows.

Everytime I execute `gradle assembleRelease` I receive following errors:

```
AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 1: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 030303P: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 1: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: Hp@3@3@3�J4�J4�J4R�td@3@3@3P+0P�tdT+T+T+��Q�td���: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 26: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 1: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: �u: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #1: Unexpected error output: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 1: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 030303P: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #1: Unexpected error output: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 1: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: Hp@3@3@3�J4�J4�J4R�td@3@3@3P+0P�tdT+T+T+��Q�td���: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #1: Unexpected error output: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 26: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #2: Unexpected error output: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 1: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 030303P: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #2: Unexpected error output: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 1: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: Hp@3@3@3�J4�J4�J4R�td@3@3@3P+0P�tdT+T+T+��Q�td���: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #2: Unexpected error output: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 1: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: ELF: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #2: Unexpected error output: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 26: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #2: Unexpected error output: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 1: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: �u: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #3: Unexpected error output: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 1: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 030303P: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #3: Unexpected error output: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 1: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: Hp@3@3@3�J4�J4�J4R�td@3@3@3P+0P�tdT+T+T+��Q�td���: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #3: Unexpected error output: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 26: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #3: Unexpected error output: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 1: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: ELF: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #3: Unexpected error output: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 1: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: �u: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #4: Unexpected error output: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 1: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 030303P: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #4: Unexpected error output: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 1: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: Hp@3@3@3�J4�J4�J4R�td@3@3@3P+0P�tdT+T+T+��Q�td���: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #4: Unexpected error output: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 26: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #5: Unexpected error output: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 1: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 030303P: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #5: Unexpected error output: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 1: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: Hp@3@3@3�J4�J4�J4R�td@3@3@3P+0P�tdT+T+T+��Q�td���: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #5: Unexpected error output: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 26: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #5: Unexpected error output: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 1: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 1: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: �u: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #5: Unexpected error output: ELF: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #6: Unexpected error output: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 1: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 030303P: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #6: Unexpected error output: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 1: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: Hp@3@3@3�J4�J4�J4R�td@3@3@3P+0P�tdT+T+T+��Q�td���: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #6: Unexpected error output: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 26: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #6: Unexpected error output: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 1: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: �u: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #6: Unexpected error output: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 1: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: ELF: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #7: Unexpected error output: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 1: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 030303P: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #7: Unexpected error output: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 1: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: Hp@3@3@3�J4�J4�J4R�td@3@3@3P+0P�tdT+T+T+��Q�td���: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #7: Unexpected error output: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: 26: /home/androidbuild/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2ec2027802609baf5b3c1f227a9b8cc7/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux/aapt2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
> Task :app:mergeReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> 8 exceptions were raised by workers:
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-linux Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
```

Has anybody encountered the same error?